# jquery setting dynamic background and hover not working with some issue

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have a big sprite image, and i just set this image as background to my 30 no.of li's background. after set the backgroud, while the hover, just i want to minus the y position to 70px, so it will reach the over bg.

for, this i am retriving the current x, y and storing, from the y i just reducing the 70px to achieve my hover position, but i am not getting properly. it works, but it very buggy, can any one correct my code to work better?

my code :

```
$('.logo-gal li').each(function(index){ // dynamically i am setting the bg, works.
        index % 5 == 0 ? y+=1 : y;
        $(this).css({
            background:'url(images/css/gall-logo.png) no-repeat',
            backgroundPosition: -((index%5) * 106)+'px '+ -(y*140) +'px'
        })

    })

    $('.logo-gal li').hover(function(){
        var backPos = $(this).css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
        var xPos = parseInt(backPos[0]),yPos = parseInt(backPos[1]);//storing x y pos.
        console.log(xPos);
        $(this).css({backgroundPosition: xPos+ (yPos-70)+"px"});// applying too.. not work, and i need to setback the stored dada, while mouseout..
    })
```

any good suggestion?

Comment: What is: *"30 no.of li's background"* ? And instead of using '5' why you don't use `.length` ?

Comment: i have 30.no of 'li' element.. each 5 will be a row, so i am using 5!

Answer (score 1):

you had problem with string cancatenation

```
$('.logo-gal li').each(function(index){ // dynamically i am setting the bg, works.
        index % 5 == 0 ? y+=1 : y;
        $(this).css({
            background:'url(images/css/gall-logo.png) no-repeat',
            backgroundPosition: '-'+eval((index%5) * 106)+'px  -'+eval(y*140) +'px'
        })

    })

    $('.logo-gal li').hover(function(){
        var backPos = $(this).css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
        var xPos = parseInt(backPos[0]),yPos = parseInt(backPos[1]);//storing x y pos.
        console.log(xPos);
        $(this).css({backgroundPosition: eval(xPos+ yPos)+"px"});// applying too.. not work, and i need to setback the stored dada, while mouseout..
    })
```